# For/In Loop Object to Array

Tags: javascript, loops, object

Can some one please explain to me in a layman's what is happening in the loop as it iterates to produce the statement (the objects properties are in an array).

```
var o = {x:1, y:2, z:3};
var a = [], i = 0;

for (a[i++] in o)
{
    console.log(o);
}
```

Comment: Something very basic for you Java != Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the for/in loop is evaluated:

```
for each property in object o
     assign the property name to the left hand side, that is a[i++]
```

Initially `i = 0`, so:

1. `a[0]` will get `x`. // notice it gets the property name, not its value
2. `a[1]` will get `y`.
3. `a[2]` will get `z`.

**NOTE:** `i++` is equal to `i = i + 1`.

The previous code is equivalent to the following:

```
var o = {x:1, y:2, z:3};
var a = []
var i = 0;

for (propertyName in o)
{
    a[i] = propertyName;
    i = i + 1;
    console.log(o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It assigns an object with three keys (x,y,z) to `o`. It assigns an empty array to `a`, and the number 0 to `i`.

The `for ( in )` loop will iterate over an object's properties, but first the condition is evaluated.

`i++` is evaluated first. The `++` is a post-increment operator and is notorious for people getting the damn thing wrong. Douglass Crockford (search for him) suggests not using it. It returns the value stored in `i` (which was 0) then increments it.

So now i is storing 1, and we're evaluating a[0], which is accessing an element in an array, except... that array is empty (we're accessing an undefined value).

It now looks at `in o`, which iterates through the keys in `o`, which there are 3 of. Thus, it iterates the loop three times. Each time it then logs the object to the console.

**Whatever this code is, I'd suggest replacing it. It shouldn't be something you want to see in code. It's confusing and surely doesn't do anything meaningful.**